# Python Pandas - df.loc - adding additional criteria not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script with the following code that is working as intended

```
Table2 = df.loc[df.Date.between('2018-11-22','2018-11-30')].groupby(df['FPYear'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum()
```

However, now i am trying to add an additional criterion in order to filter on a column called "region" which has the value Canada in the dataset but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
Table2 = df.loc[df.Date.between('2018-11-22','2018-11-30'), df['Region'] = 'Canada'].groupby(df['FPYear'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum()
```

The additional filter seems to have no impact.  Can anyone help. Thanks

Comment: You can combine boolean sequences using `&`.

Comment: how would i adjust my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Alaxander

Here's an example snippet:

```
import pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1,2,3],
    "B": [4,5,6],
    "C": [1,1,1]
})

df.loc[((d["A"]==1) & (d["B"]==4)), ["A", "B"]]
```

Also, you might want to look at the assignment operator used in `df["Region"] = "Canada"`, shouldn't it be `==` for it to be used as a filter? I have added this as well in your code below.

Your code if you want specific fields:

```
Table2 = df.loc[((df.Date.between('2018-11-22','2018-11-30')) & (df['Region'] == 'Canada')), ["Date", "Region"]].groupby(df['FPYear'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum()
```

Your code if you want all the fields:

```
Table2 = df.loc[((df.Date.between('2018-11-22','2018-11-30')) & (df['Region'] == 'Canada'))].groupby(df['FPYear'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum()
```

PS: Thanks to @Alexandar for mentioning about the mistake.

Comment: Made the changes thanks and added all possible variations :) Thanks for pointing out @AlexanderCécile

Answer (score 0):

i figured this out by doing the following

```
Table2 = df.loc[df.Date.between('2018-11-22','2018-11-30') & (df['Region'] == 'Canada')].groupby(df['FPYear'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum() #with date filters for table
```